# Vue Apollo, trigger query when clicking button

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

We can use the

```
apollo: {....}
```

for queries when a component is mounted, but how do i trigger a new query when clicking eg: a button?

I know I can do something like:

```
<button @click="someFn">Click me</button>
```

and then do

```
methods: {
   someFn() {
     this.apollo.query({query: myQuery})     
   }
}
```

But im not sure if this is the prettiest when both having the for triggering queries.

```
apollo: {}, methods: {....}
```

Isn't there someway you can define the query inside the apollo object, and call this when clicking a button? But wihout the query getting triggered when the component is mounted? Or is the only solution to use

`this.$apollo.query({})`

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/36

Comment: awesome man, that was the thing I was looking for.